# Why didn't Doctor Strange use the Eye of Agamotto to heal his hands?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange

In *Doctor Strange* it was shown that Eye Of Agamotto can be used to manipulate time for even a specific object (as in the case of the apple). Why didn't Dr. Strange use it to heal his hands.

Answer (score 20):

Because it doesn't matter anymore to Doctor Strange.

When he gets the Eye Of Agamotto, things go fast paced and he didn't have any opportunity to do so. In the end, he accepted his role and learned his lesson. He is not going to mess with time for his selfish goals anymore. He did mess with time but only to save mankind.

Also, we don't know if the Eye of Agamotto is able to fix one body part without affecting everything else. Because time-reversing his whole body might affect his newly earned skills.

Comment: Yes and i would agree with that but as i also commented on Austin's answer. "That seems pretty sufficient but before he realizes that sorcery is more about protecting world from mystical dangers, he was selfish and wanted to heal his body other than any thing. And it was one of primary reasons why he used eye of agamotto. Seems quite ironical to me!"

Answer (score 6):

Almost as soon as Doctor Strange begins to mess with the Eye he's told that he should never touch it again, due to how dangerous it is.

Of course he does use it again, but only when the alternative is the destruction of this reality. I doubt he'd risk tearing apart reality just to heal his hands. Especially considering that he learns from the Ancient One that he can heal his hands by channeling magic through them. Why risk tearing apart reality when you can accomplish the same task through relatively trivial magic?

Comment: That seems pretty sufficient but before he realizes that sorcery is more about protecting world from mystical dangers, he was selfish and wanted to heal his body other than any thing. And it was one of primary reasons why he used eye of agamotto. Seems quite ironical to me!

Comment: Well remember, after he first discovers the eyes, things are happening pretty much nonstop that keep him from being able to heal himself, and by the time he even has the chance to heal himself, he is told by the Ancient One that he doesn't even need anything as drastic as time magic. He could just channel energy through his hands! If things hadn't gotten so hectic immediately after his discovering the eye, I think he might have tried to heal his hands in that way